# How to tell CMake to loosen the requirement for Python version?

Tags: python, cmake

When I build OpenCV-dnn with CMake along this lines:

https://towardsdev.com/installing-opencv-4-with-cuda-in-ubuntu-20-04-fde6d6a0a367

at the stage of cmake command I get

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version “3.8.14”, but required is exact version “3.8.13”.
```

How can I change the requirement to “3.8.13-14” to try if it works? I don’t want to break the dev server just to try building the artefact. Or is this hardwired inside of the library?

---

Update. After installing conda with Python 3.8.13 I get

After creating and activating Python 3.8.13 Anaconda environment I get

```
– Found PythonInterp: /home/sam/anaconda3/envs/cvdnn/bin/python3 (found suitable version “3.8.13”, minimum required is “3.2”)
– Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version “3.8.14”, but required is exact version “3.8.13” (found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so)
```

So PythonInterp finds the required version 3.8.13, but PythonLibs falls back to system version and cmake fails there.

Comment: delete your cmake cache and try again

Comment: related (probably): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: download a Docker container with cvdnn installed. Works out of the box.